# How to read a file into a database? some row don't match the column number

Tags: mysql, linux

i got this txt file with 40 million rows and i need to load all the rows into a database table i have already use LOAD FILE command but it stops because some rows don't match the amount of columns need by the table scheme. any solution would be appreciate even any alternative to the LOAD FILE command

Comment: Do you have too many columns in your file or too few?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have amount of columns in the file is fewer than the table scheme, i have already fix the thing, i just need to implement some terminated by statement and works fine, thanks all to take the time to read this dumb question

Answer (score 1):

The [load data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) manual entries show how to ignore columns:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);
```

In this case your file has 5 columns of which only the first, third and fifth are wanted.